# How to fix the problem model.fit(df[['size2']]) NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm trying to detect an animal but I have the following problem:
NameError: name 'df' is not defined

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 import seaborn as sns
 from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest


 data = pd.read_csv('P.csv',encoding='latin-1', on_bad_lines='skip',index_col=0, header=0, 
 engine='python')

 model = IsolationForest(n_estimators = 100, max_samples = 'auto', contamination = 'auto')
 model.fit(df[['P']])
 df['size2'] = model.decision_function(df[['P']])
 df['anomaly']= model.predict(df[['P']])
 df = func_nb()
 print(df.head(50))
 anomaly = df.loc[df['anomaly']==-1]
 df = func_nb()
 anomaly_index = list(anomaly.index)
 print(anomaly)
```

Comment: Where is `df` defined? Also, that error message does not match the code you provided.

Comment: Typo? use `data` instead of `df` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error suggests, it seems that you defined `data` when you actually wanted to define `df`. Therefore, changing this line from:

```
data = pd.read_csv('P.csv',encoding='latin-1', on_bad_lines='skip',index_col=0, header=0,
```

To:

```
df = pd.read_csv('P.csv',encoding='latin-1', on_bad_lines='skip',index_col=0, header=0,
```

Would probably solve your issue.